# Application access from C# application fails

Tags: c#, azure

I registred a small application under Azure Portal -> App Registration. I am trying to access with secret key.

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + MyConstants.tenantID);
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(MyConstants.applicationId, MyConstants.authenticationKey);
AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred)
{
    SubscriptionId = MyConstants.subscriptionId
};
```

How to I get the `authenticationKey`?

I tried using client Secret but it does not work

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + MyConstants.tenantID);
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(MyConstants.applicationId, MyConstants.authenticationKey);
AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred)
{
    SubscriptionId = MyConstants.subscriptionId
};
```

> "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '270d74fc-4085-43ff-ab1e-e2dba48461e0' was not found in the directory 'e2454f92-2891-4670-9402-f17f4cef17de'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
>
> Trace ID: cee6d534-7d75-4fcb-a5e9-0d93ab88af00\r\nCorrelation ID: 3b74b95e-a33a-410d-9e4e-82eef4a81817
>   Timestamp: 2019-11-11 10:51:43Z ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest)

Comment: Please do some effort on actually formatting your code and extracting the errors so it doesn't look like just a wall of unformatted text next time

Comment: The error message suggests that the secret key is probably not the issue. It's complaining that you are using an Application ID which does not exist, or the application has not been configured correctly yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you provide,  the application id you use does not exist in the tenant or you do not complete admin content. If you want to use client credentials flow to get access token and call API, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). The detailed steps are as below.
1. Register an Azure AD apllication 
[image]

2. Assign an RABC role to the application.
   Because you want to create Azure data factory, you can assign`Data Factory Contributor role`role  to the application. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#azure-roles).

   a. Click the subscription where you want to grant access.

   b. Click Access control (IAM).

   c. Click the Role assignments tab to view all the role assignments for this subscription.

   d. Click Add > Add role assignment to open the Add role assignment pane.
   [image]
   [image]
3. code

```
string tenantID = "<your tenant ID>";
string applicationId = "<your application ID>";
string authenticationKey = "<your client secret for the application>";
string subscriptionId = "<your subscription ID where the data factory resides>";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey);
AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
    "https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) {
    SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
```

Comment: Yes, this works by re-creating  the application on Azure and then using the Application Keys

Comment: @RashidQuamar  According to my understanding, your issue has been resolved. If so, could you please accept the answer?